# App Engine Managed VM custom runtime app.yaml login: admin

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to run a Jenkins server in a Docker container, as a GAE Managed VM 'custom runtime'

I want to use the app.yaml to enforce `login: admin` auth

Docs say:

> It isn't necessary to define a handler stanza in your config file. If your application is serving only dynamic requests, the handler stanza can be omitted. If you want to set up a secure URL for dynamic requests, use login: admin with an otherwise empty handler.

If I don't define the `handler` stanza then Jenkins web UI works fine, but I have no auth on the url.

I have tried the following variations but they all lead to symptom where the Jenkins dashboard loads, but all static files are all broken and can't act because js not loaded

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  login: admin

handlers:
- login: admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the working stanza:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: dynamic
  login: admin
```